# JQuery Datepicker and Command button

Tags: mysql, datepicker

I have a date picker to select a specific date from and that should match with the data in MySQL table.

Here is the code :

```
    $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                });

$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "onSelect", function (dateText, inst) {              
                      ...do something... 

             });
     });
```

If I select a date from the date picker then return data correctly from the MySQL table. But I want to execute the command by the following manner :

1. First -> select a date from date picker
2. Second -> Press a command button like "Show"
3. Third -> Then return the relevant data set from MySQL table

I'm not sure what I'm going wrong. Can anyone help me ?..

Comment: If I understand correctly, remove on selected callback, add button show and attach on click event to it.

Comment: Can you modify my code with your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "onSelect", function (dateText, inst) {              })
```

And add new event:

```
$("#button_id").on('click', function()   {
 // make request to db

 });
```

In html:

```
<button id="button_id">show</button>
```